# Ignore directory name with find

Tags: linux, find

So with grep we can do grep -r --exclude-dir=badDirName searchTerm

Is there similar functionality for find where I can exclude looking ALL directories with a specific name?

I've seen people use -prune or -not -path but that only seems to be for a specific path. However, I have a specific directory name that exists multiple times in multiple levels of indentation that I want to exclude from the search.

Thanks!

Comment: `-not -path '*/subdir/*'`?